# Ruby: Convert big .xml files to csv

Tags: ruby, xml, csv, nokogiri

I have a little problem.
I need to convert large xml files (1-4GB each) to CSV.
I know that I can do this with Nokogiri's SAX parser, but I'm stuck.

```
<Documents>
    <Document DocID="10170306" DocType="Message">
    <FieldValues>

        <E03>-1166737392</E03>
        <E05>petrosky (petrosky@foo.com)</E05>
        <E06>00000000B89476181EE6C34FB4E9D87F9E44A85944002000</E06>
        <E07>\foo-dedup-global.mbox_99.mbox\</E07>
        <E08>5/12/2011 6:32:38 PM</E08>
        <E09>Fwd: important decision for v1 launch</E09>
        <E10>Susan Infantino (susani@foo.com); Mike Yang (foo@mail.com)</E10>
        <F01>Jun  8 2011  7:43AM</F01>
        <F02>May 12 2011  6:32PM</F02>
        <F03>Msg0002_important decisi.html</F03>
        <F04>MSMAIL</F04>
        <F05>CA4DBB95C638FB656CB02627DDEA90C9</F05>
        <F06>28677</F06>
        <F07>foo-dedup-global.mbox_99.mbox.pst</F07>
        <F08>10164846</F08>
        <F09>10170306</F09>
        <E11>0</E11>
        <E12>&lt;BANLkTi=yztN5Pd0v9i9+zN=aYhAo5Y8ffA@mail.foo.com&gt;</E12>

    </FieldValues>
    <Files>
      <File FileType="Native">
        <ExternalFile FilePath="\04_EXT\31\foo-dedup-global.mbox_99.mbox.pst10164846.dir\foo-dedup-global.mbox_99.mbox\" FileName="Msg0002_important decisi.html" FileSize="28677" Hash="CA4DBB95C638FB656CB02627DDEA90C9" HashType="MD5" />
      </File>
    </Files>
    <Locations>
      <Location>
        <Custodian>Yang_Mike</Custodian>
        <LocationURI>\\ANNATXCIFS02\PN_Dunbar_F01401\04_EXT\31\foo-dedup-global.mbox_99.mbox.pst10164846.dir\foo-dedup-global.mbox_99.mbox\Msg0002_important decisi.html</LocationURI>
      </Location>
    </Locations>    
  </Document>
</Documents>
```

I played a littlebit around with event driven programming.

```
require 'fileutils'
require 'faster_csv'
require 'nokogiri'

file = ARGV[0]

include Nokogiri

class Xmlfile < XML::SAX::Document
  def start_element name, attrs
    # Process data here
    if name == 'Document'
      documentName = [*attrs]
      puts documentName
    end     
    if name == 'File'
      file = [*attrs]
      puts file
    end
    if name == 'ExternalFile'
      externalFile = [*attrs]
      puts externalFile 
    end
  end

#   def end_element name, attrs
#   end

end

parser = XML::SAX::Parser.new(Xmlfile.new)
parser.parse_file(file)
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem/question? The code above works, i.e. it outputs all attributes of all `Document`, `File` and `ExternalFile` nodes.

Comment: @undur_gongor he wants to convert it to CSV, it's in the title.

Comment: pls attach how are you going to map parts of your xml file to csv columns.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're outputting the information you need in your `puts`, and attempting to capture the data into variables. You are missing the part where you do something with the variables to send the data to the CSV generator.

You can append `documentName`, `file` and `externalFile` to an Array and pass that to CSV.

The [CSV documentation](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/) shows several nice ways to generate output. Check out the "Writing" section for more information.

From the docs:

```
FasterCSV.open("path/to/file.csv", "w") do |csv|
  csv << ["row", "of", "CSV", "data"]
  csv << ["another", "row"]
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Here's the standard library documentation for CSV: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Comment: How do you dynamically add xml to the CSV with Ruby? I've been able to write to the CSV but it will only enter the data in one row - so as it iterates it's continually overwritten.

Comment: You need to ask your question as a new question, not as a comment to an answer. There's no possible way for us to answer you With the little we know about your situation.